# Can simplemodal confirm hold the function?

Tags: simplemodal, confirm

Can simplemodal confirm  hold the function? Like alert(),the codes after the alert() will not be runned before you click it . I tried , but it doesn't work like this. (My English is poor , so ...)

Answer (score 0):

Simple model has 2 parameters. confirm(message, callback). 
Pass your code as JS function to call back parameter.

```
confirm("Are you sure you want to logout", function () {
            //Your code here 
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")';
        });
```